# What should be path for the files that are in resources folder in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration

I want to access the certificate file what should be the path if that file is in **resources/certs/** folder.

I tried it with the `classpath` put still getting the exception `FileNotFound`.

what should be path for that I should specify for this in my **application.properties**.

[image]

Comment: classpath:certs/teye-feeds.jks is correct, as long as your Maven builds the package with the contents of src/main/resources in the classpath.

Comment: The code structure is maven based as you can see `src/main/resource`.

Comment: I can see that.  What I can't see is how Maven builds your package.  I assumed that you would follow convention for either executable JAR or WAR file.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to read a file, you can use this code (fileName: "/certs/xxx")

```
public String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
        StringBuilder resultStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                resultStringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        }
        return resultStringBuilder.toString();
    }
```